# Color settings with helm

Tags: helm, faces, highlighting, customize-face

I use helm a lot. I have a problem setting colors. In my `init.el` I have

```lisp
(require 'helm)
(require 'helm-config)

;; change active line color
(set-face-attribute 'helm-selection nil 
                   :background "red"
                   :foreground "white")
```

Supose I have the situation in the picture below where I search for `XXX`. In `C` the helm-occur buffer uses red/white colors for the selected line. But in the parent buffer in point `B` I still have green and purple for the pattern match. I'd like to change the colors in `B` so that they match what happens in `C`. I suppose I should do something like the code above, but I don't understand what controls the colors in `B`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, instead of the code you're using to customize face `helm-selection`, just use `M-x customize-face`, and save your changes.  Using Customize is nearly always a better idea.

---

To your question:

Put your cursor on the text whose face you want to know, e.g. the face you say is "green and purple", and use `C-u C-x =`. The `*Help*` buffer will tell you (near the bottom) what faces are present at that position.

Then use `M-x customize-face` to customize that face (likewise, any others).
When customizing you can even define a face to just inherit from some other face. Easy-peasy.